# What is the difference between "can't" and "mustn't" in the expressing of prohibition?

Tags: differences, negation, modal-verbs

> You **[verb]** use your mobile phone while you're driving. It's against the law.

What verb should be used?

- don't have to
- needn't
- mustn't
- can't

Is *can't* correct, or only *mustn't* is correct?
What is the difference?

Comment: Your last sentence needs serious help.  Try *Is "can't" correct or ...*

Comment: Technically, "can't" means that the proposed activity is physically impossible, while "mustn't" means that the activity is prohibited.  However, this technical distinction is often ignored.

Comment: In GenAmE, the idiomatic phrasing is 'You _shouldn't_ ...' meaning 'You are not allowed to to...' . "Mustn't" means mostly the same but is just not used as often as "shouldn't".  Also, I hope language learners are told how to pronounce it as /mʌsnt/. The spelling pronunciation of /mʌstnt/ is _impossible_ for English speakers.

Answer (score 10):

I mustn't X means that it is imperative that I not do X.

I can't X means that it is not possible for me to do X.

Therefore, mustn't is the correct answer.

However, in colloquial speech, people would use the word "can't", since it is implied in the statement that you cannot use your mobile phone without breaking the law.

Comment: Notice the lack of parallelism here: *cannot* = "not possible to do", *may not* = "not permitted to do", *need not* = "not required to do", but *must not* = "required to not do".

Comment: -1 Mustn't isn't the only possible answer to the question, you contradicted yourself when you claim that "can" is used in colloquial speech, ( which is true) so what's to stop it from being written?

Comment: In some contexts, _can_ and _can not_ refer to physical impossibility, while _must not_ and _may not_ refer to unacceptable acts. Colloquially _can not_ is used for this, too. But the traffic laws will use phrasing like "must not use a cellphone", not "can not use a cellphone".

Comment: @AndrewLazarus Can has different meanings; ability, possibility and permission. How would you define the meaning of: "Can I park here?" You could interpret in all 3 manners but normally you would be asking if parking was allowed. The same reasoning applies to the negative form:"I can't park here". Therefore it is common to hear and read: "**I can't use my mobile here."**

Comment: The OP question contains the pronoun **I** not the pronoun, it. It is perfectly correct to use either mustn't or can't in the phrase, hence the question is flawed. In traffic laws the more usual terms are: "It is **forbidden** to use mobiles while driving", or "The use of mobiles is not **allowed** while driving", or more simply: "It **is against the law** to use a mobile etc." **Must** and **must not** can be seen on notices but they are issued by the authority in charge. **"You must not speak during the exam"** are instructions written by a school or by an examining board.

Comment: @Mari-LouA, Sure, usually. But I have been known to ask my passengers "Can I park there?" in the sense of "Can I maneuver the car into that small space?" The passengers can see that it is a permitted parking place, and they understand that I am referring to my skills, not permission. (I'm not great at parking a car.) The point of my comment is that words like _can_, _must_, and _shall_ often take on a more specific meaning in regulatory or legal contexts. I am not sure if you disagree.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus I did say that can is used for possibility, ability AND for permission. "Can" is ambiguous and explains why non-native speakers at the beginning do get confused. In your legitimate example, "Can I park here?" put in a different context, you might be asking for permission. You are in a foreign country and you do not understand the signs so you ask in order to be sure. In _your_ context you were referring to your *ability* as a motorist.

Comment: Unambiguous (just for those who are picky): The law prohibits the use of cell phones while driving. Ergo, I mustn't use. Ergo, I can't use it.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to choose a word from that list I would opt for "**mustn't**".

Luckily, I [**don't have to**](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/have-to?q=have+to) because I would say something completely different, i.e: "**Don't** use your mobile while driving. It's against the law."

> "You **mustn't use** your mobile phone while you're driving. It's against the law."

The following is a *possible* scenario:

I am driving in my car with my mother sitting next to me. My mobile rings and instinctively I reach to answer it. My mother looks at me sternly (or with deep concern) and tells me:
"You mustn't use your mobile."

I am like a *child* being told what to do by her parent, in this case her authority is greater than mine. *Must* is often used by individuals whose authority is greater than ours, (I am simplifying here but it's generally true) and is also used for giving emphatic advice:

"You **must take** more exercise. Join a gym."

However, **can't** is also acceptable if the situation changes:

> "You **can't use** your mobile phone while you're driving. It's
> against the law."

This time I am driving in my car but I have a *friend* sitting next to me, and (s)he reminds me that I am breaking the law. (S)he does not have any authority over me, we are equal.

We use "can" and "cannot" to talk about having *permission* to do or not do something.

"**I can't use my mobile**" can mean *I am not allowed*; *it is not allowed by the police/the law* or *it is not right thing to do.*

*Don't have to* and *needn't* both mean that something is unnecessary, they have completely different meanings from *can't* and *mustn't*.

[**can**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/can) and [**must**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/must?s=t)

Answer (score 2):

Correct completions for that blank would be "may not" (the abbreviation "mayn't" is very unusual) and "shouldn't".  Quick illustration:

> *May I use my mobile phone while driving?*

*No, you may not.* or "No, you must **never** use your mobile phone while driving."

> *Should I use my mobile phone while driving?*

*No, you shouldn't.*

None of the options suggested form any relation to the obvious sense of the sentence in relation to being against the law.  "Mustn't" comes closest.

Another good alternative is *You must **disuse** your mobile phone while driving.* (Not only may you not start using it while driving, you must stop if you were already using it.)

Comment: When would you use "mustn't" properly?

Comment: @Bogdan: "Mustn't" introduces possible confusion.  Does "not" modify must, thence "You are not required to use" or "use", thence "You are required to not use".  The latter case is desired here, and "You must *never* use a mobile phone while driving." is far clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Oxford Dictionaries Online says that *can't* is simply a contraction for *can not*, and [the entry for *can*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/can?region=us&rskey=sZFHfR&result=1) includes this definition and examples:

> 2 be permitted to:
>
> - *you can use the phone if you want to*
> - *nobody could legally drink on the premises*

The word is certainly used that way in conversation all the time, and [sometimes](http://www.abajournal.com/news/article/disbarred_law_grad_cant_use_j.d._after_his_name_judge_rules) in the [news](http://www.businessweek.com/news/2011-06-09/toyota-owners-can-t-use-california-law-in-economic-loss-suit.html). But not too often. It's more common for an attention-grabbing headline to use the word *can't* above an article that instead uses more formal words like [*prevent*](http://www.news4jax.com/news/28161205/detail.html), [*prohibit*](http://www.freakonomics.com/2011/05/19/why-cant-law-firms-go-public/), [*has no authority*](http://articles.sun-sentinel.com/2011-04-27/business/pb-attorney-general-foreclosure-20110427_1_shapiro-fishman-stern-firm-foreclosure-law), or [*cannot legally*](http://blogs.miaminewtimes.com/shortorder/2011/03/miami-dade_zoning_says_food_tr_1.php).

Oxford Dictionaries Online includes this usage note:

> Is there any difference between **can** and **may** when used to request or express permission, as in ***may*** I ask you a few questions? or ***can*** I ask you a few questions? Many people feel that **can** should be reserved for expressions denoting capability, as in ***can*** you swim?, rather than for those relating to permission. **May** is, generally speaking, a politer and more formal way of asking for something, and is the better choice in more formal contexts.

Answer (score 0):

I think in the context of the original sentence,'can't' expresses that using your mobile phone while driving is not allowed, and 'mustn't' expresses necessity to not do it. In this context either can be used, but that's not always the case.

eg. *Some people think that home-schooled students can't sit high school exams* - 'mustn't' would not fit here.